# Azure Datafactory Expression of If Condition activity with multiple check

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have to check condition for while getting API call web activity output in forEach, i have to check each calls to validate the success or failed my API. so that I have to implemented inside forEach activity to check IF Condition Activity.

The IF condition activity, I have to declare my multiple check based on below response.
My response key will be change StatusCode : 200 or SourceId:value

My source of web activity is web API, for example :

```
activity('webApi').output.StatusCode 
activity('webApi').output.SourceId
```

every time I have to check StatusCode==200 or SourceId key available or not.

web API response :

Response : 1

```
{
    "SourceId": "test",
    "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "X-Content": ""
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "IR_Test(IrTest-Dev)",
    "executionDuration": 0,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 5
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "SelfhostedIR",
                "duration": 3433434343,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Response : 2

```
{
    "StatusCode":200,
    "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "X-Content": ""
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "IR_Test(IrTest-Dev)",
    "executionDuration": 0,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 5
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "SelfhostedIR",
                "duration": 3433434343,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

above two kind of response, I will be getting every time, based on that, I have to check condition in my expression in if condition activity. please help me.

I have tried below condition in expression:

```
@and(equals(activity('webapi').output.StatusCode,'200'),
or(equals(activity('webapi').output.SourceId,'SourceId')))
```

but it is not working, always throwing sourceId missing or Statuscode missing.

Comment: Could you share the overall response of webapi? How do you get response1 and response2 separately?

Comment: i am calling webapi in foreach loop, sometime response will be come response 1(as i shared) and sometime response will be come response 2 ( as i already shared).. let say that if start loop 1...to 100.. i am getting first iteration is sourceId and second iteration response statuscode:200

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the `activity('webapi').output` contains the property before accessing it. You need to know that you can access the properties like on every JSON like this: `jsonObject['propertyName']`

Example for StatusCode, if it does not find it, I will return here just 404 (maybe you can also put another number, but I would choose a value of the same datatype as the existing property).

```
if(contains(activity('webapi').output, 'StatusCode'), 
   activity('webapi').output['StatusCode'],
   404)
```

So your example would work like this I guess:

```
@or(
  equals(
    if(contains(activity('webapi').output, 'StatusCode'), 
      activity('webapi').output['StatusCode'],
      404),
    200),
  equals(
    if(contains(activity('webapi').output, 'SourceId'), 
      activity('webapi').output['SourceId'],
      ''),
  'test'))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: above that sample not working, if condition TRUE or FALSE activity always going FALSE so that expected result not coming

Comment: It had one bracket too many at the end and I changed the last check with 'test' like in your response 1. It should work that way and not always return FALSE. I tested it. Is your activity called webapi or webApi? You have both versions in your question. It is case sensitive. And TRUE OR FALSE is TRUE and not FALSE. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The question is if your Response 2 has `"StatusCode":200,` like in your question or if it is `"StatusCode": "200",` because then you need of course compare a string and not a number.

Comment: my response two different only the key will be change like stautscode or sourceid so that i have to check if statscode==200 or sourceid key coming or not both any one condition satisfied then i have to proceed further

Comment: Hi, I will be get webapi response from my web activity . @string(activity('webapi').output.StatusCode) or @string(activity('webapi').output.sourceId) but i want to handle status code ==200 to store in my column and also if it is source id, i have to hardcoded 200 value store in my column. please suggest

Comment: at a time either one value will come from my source web api

Comment: Maybe you mean something like this? `@or(and(contains(activity('webapi').output,'StatusCode'),equals(activity('webapi').output['StatusCode'], '200')),contains(activity('webapi').output,'SourceId'))`

Comment: (maybe you also have to put `200` instead of `'200'` depending on the datatype (string or number))

Answer (score 0):

Since you get different response from webapi in each iteration, it is necessary to check if the webapi output has `sourceid` or `sourcecode` parameter and then give the condition.

**Expression in IF**

```
@if(contains(activity('Web1').output,'SourceId'),
equals(activity('Web1').output.SourceId, 'test'),
if(contains(activity('Web1').output,'SourceCode'),equals(activity('Web1').output.StatusCode,'200'),0))
```

The above expression checks if the output of a previous Web activity contains a `SourceId` property. If it does, then it checks if the value of the `SourceId` property is equal to `'test'`. If the `SourceId` property is not present or its value is not equal to `'test'`, then the expression checks, if the output of the previous web activity contains a `StatusCode` property. If it does, then it checks if the value of the `StatusCode` property is equal to `'200'`. If the `StatusCode` property is not present or its value is not equal to `'200'`, then the expression returns `false`.

[image]

Comment: Hi @aswin - the sourceId value we do not want to check, i have check if the sourceId coming from response or not and other response stauscode is 200 not. both condition i need to check same time

Comment: I mean sourceId key need to check and other response statuscode value is 200 or not

Comment: Did you mean this? `@and(equals(activity('Web1').output.StatusCode,'200'),contains(activity('Web1').output,'SourceId'))`

Comment: statuscode needs to take activity('Web1').output.StatusCode and if activity('Web1').output.sourceId comes, we have to hardcode 200

Comment: above output always return TRUE so that my column value sit in DB data True..instead of that i need to store 200 dynamic from statuscode and sourceid needs to hardcode

Comment: @or(
    if(contains(activity('webapi').output, 'StatusCode'), 
      activity('webapi').output.StatusCode,
      404),
    activity('webapi').output.StatusCode,
    if(contains(activity('webapi').output, 'SourceId'), 
      activity('webapi').output.SourceId,
      '404'),
  '200')

Comment: Any error, here?